# Django Password Validation string

Tags: python, django, validation

Is there Any Possible change to change Django Validation string kinda like this :

Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and `@/./+/-/_` only.

I want different  validation rule  where can i find this ??  or is it possible to change i am using django auth system

Comment: Have you read the documentation about [password validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation)? It explains how to [write your own validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#writing-your-own-validator).

Comment: hmm i will read it again thank you maybe i missed something

Answer (score 0):

You can always overwrite the property of any build in Django model.

sample:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class User(AbstractUser):
    password = CharField(
        max_length=150,
        required=True, #if you want that field to be mandatory
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                regex='^([-\w]+)$',
                message='your custom error message',
            ),
        ]
     )
```